# How to start an activity after signing in with Google?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-api

I'm trying to start an activity with `Intent` after signing in with Google. It signs in but doesn't start the activity. In the `onClick()` I've written:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_sign_in:
            // Signin button clicked
            signInWithGplus();
            break;
```

And here is the method `signInWithGplus()`:

```
  private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, GOOGLE_SIGIN);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

I've written `Intent` in `onConnected` but it doesn't react, it signs in and nothing more:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Velkommen!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Forside.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Currently I'm running the app on an emulator (Google Api). Futhermore I get a message in the console that the storage is insufficient. Is this causing the issue? I've searched on Google and here on Stackoverflow before posting this, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Most likely.  It seems that you don't have storage (did you request the storage permission?) and thus aren't actually logging in.  Since you don't get logged in, onConnected isn't called.

Comment: Ok, how do I do that? I've tried `android:installLocation="auto"`

Comment: Have looked at the Google settings in the emulator, it seems that I'm signed in

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `this` has a different meaning inside the handler.

Change

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Forside.class);
```

To

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityClassName.this, Forside.class);
```

Comment: It's the same after I sign in, it doesn't start the activity. However, I also get this message in the console : `Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used`